# Why do the [3d-printer] and [3d-printing] tags exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the most popular tag (82 questions tagged) is [3d-printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-printer), and that we also have a [3d-printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-printing) tag (23 questions). These seem extremely redundant to me, given that they *should* apply to any question that is on-topic and thus serve no practical purpose. These tags are simply too broad.

The usage guidance for 3d-printer is quite board ("Questions about a specific brand, model, or type of 3D printer.") and 3d-printing does not even have one.

I would suggest to get rid of these tags. For comparison, [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) does not have a programming tag either. However, they do have various tags that end in "-programming", such as "functional-programming", "linear-programming", etc... Our equivalents would be fdm(-printing), sla(-printing),...

Comment: Good point. I agree. Anyone against? If not, I'll try to remember deleting it tomorrow.

Comment: I agree as well. I believe we do have tags for FDM, SLA, and so forth already.

Comment: @TormodHaugene Poke.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, thanks! I have now merged the two tags in [3d-printing](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-printing), and will now try to get a community moderator to blacklist (make it intrinsic) for us. (Site moderators does not have the privilege to actually delete tags.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag has been removed from the system and made intrinsic.

[Please cleanup the questions that now have no tags...](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it is done now

Comment: @tbm0115 - I have just retagged 8 of the existing 23 untagged questions.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there is a synonym appears to be the reason that both tags are still hanging around, in the [list of synonyms](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms):

> [image: Synonyms]

and on the tag page

> [image: 3d-printer tag]

I have deleted the synonym and hopefully that will clear things up once and for all.