# Why is there a 3D-printing badge?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm a bit confused as to why there is a badge targeting a specific tag [3d-printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-printing). I don't know what came first the tag or the badge, but it poses a potential flaw on either side.

We agreed to merge 3d-printer and 3d-printing tags in [another meta post](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/why-do-the-3d-printer-and-3d-printing-tags-exist). I don't see it pull up in the [badge list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

So, should we merge tags in the other direction now, change the badge, or not worry about it?

Comment: Is there I 3d-printing badge? I can't seem to find it. ;-)

Comment: It popped up in my profile as a "Do you want to track this badge?"